# How to apply front page(customized) design to the entire RESPONSIVE template

Tags: php, css

I’ve installed responsive theme and responsive master child also.

I’ve designed a custom front page design and I want the same design on the entire website.

Here is the website:
http://fulnet.org/

and here is the website pages.

http://fulnet.org/what-we-do/

Basicly I want to modify the header menu area and the footer.
I dont want the sliders and the rest only the menu and the footer area.
PLease help me I’m new in working with wordpress and I’ve spent the last two weeks trying to made this changes, but not succeeded.

Thank you for your time and for help,

Ionut

Answer (score 0):

If you want the header and footer to be accessible on all the pages, just include the wp_header & wp_footer on your pages files.

Comment: This answer needs more details to be useful as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, you have a static html page: http://fulnet.org/.

On the other, you have a Wordpress Theme: http://fulnet.org/what-we-do/

What you need to do is to make the neccessary changes in your `style.css` inside your Wordpress Theme - `wp-content/themes/responsive`.